# Retrieve Data From Mandrillapp Dashboard

Tags: javascript, c#, mandrill

I have searched so much about mandrill api , but there is no good documentation at all . The question is , How can i get some information from dashboard of mandrillapp.com ( For example : on the picture i defined them by red circles ) .  there are many APIs but i did not find anything in this case . please give me a sample in javascript or c#

[image]

Comment: There's great documentation with examples at: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/.

Comment: @Quotidian Thank u so much .